# How to prevent inherited Maven plugin execution to spread to the subchildren POMs?

Tags: java, maven

I have a lots of modules composed with various submodules. I was using a dependency check plugin execution on every parent POMs, with `<inherited>false</inherited>` because the behavior I wanted was to not execute the dependency check for every child POMs, only the parent one. The tree is something like this:

```
Module1 (POM) to dependency check
  subModule1 (pom)
  subModule2 (pom)
Module2 (POM) to dependency check
  subModule1 (pom)
```

What I want to do is to move the plugin execution declared in every of these parent POMs to one profile declared in a higher parent POM they all inherit from. The tree changes to this:

```
"Super" POM with profile
  Module1 (POM) to dependency check
   subModule1 (pom)
     subModule2 (pom)
  Module2 (POM) to dependency check
      subModule1 (pom)
```

I made this:

```
    <profile>
        <id>dependencycheck</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

My issue is that if I state `<inherited>false</inherited>` here the execution of the plugin isn't spread to the children. If I remove it, then the children execute the plugin when I explicitly use the profile  *but it is also executed on the subchildren POMs*, which was the behavior I was trying to avoid.

Is there a way to only spread the execution to the first degree children or something like this ? I couldn't find anything so far.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property which you can use in the plugin configuration of your profile and override the property in the childrens `pom.xml`:

```
    <properties>
        <pluginskip>false</pluginskip> 
    </properties>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
        <configuration>
             <skip>${pluginskip}</skip>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This doesn't really solve my issue as when the children which sets the skip to false through a property triggers the dependency check it does it for all of its submodules which is what I want to avoid, and it does it even if these POMs have 'skip' set to "true". This is because "inherited" is set to "true" in the main parent, which I need to do otherwise the profile is only applied to the main parent and that defeats the purpose of what I want to do. But I don't want that inheritance to go down the full route, only to the first level of children.

Comment: I also tried to put "inherited" value in a property, set to true in the main parent and "false" in the children that need to execute the profile without spreading it to their own children but it doesn't work, it seems the "inherited" tag of the plugin can't receive property values.